# Separating string in java using regex

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, indexing, split

I have a `String str="[12] word1 word2 (12.4%)"`

what i need is to get only the `word1 word2` and replace the space with underscore output should be like this `word1_word2`

and after that how can I make it dynamically like for example the str might words might increment like `word1_word2_word3_etc`

how can I make a code shortest way as possible?

Comment: Shortest code possible for that kind of string manipulation: Use **Regular Expressions**. Now do a web search for Regular Expressions, learn how it works, and write some code. Good luck!

Comment: yea I used that like this ` String newstr = results.get(0).toString().replaceAll("[[^a-zA-Z]]", "");`

but word will just print without a space
if I could only get atleast space on each word i could replace it with underscore, any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Yeah, don't eliminate space. If you have code you've tried, show it in the question. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: how can I achieve that with getting only the words and spaces in regex? the  answer below works but im still curios how can I do that

Comment: `str = str.replaceFirst(".*]\\s*", "").replaceFirst("\\s*\\(.*", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "_")`, i.e. remove the prefix you don't want, remove the suffix you won't want, then replace spaces with underscores.

Comment: WOW! THA WAS SO GOOD! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use split() to split the words. Then use string builder to group them together.

The general idea should look like this (may not 100% correct):

```
String[] words = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// So don't include the first and last word as they are "[12]" and "(12.4%)".
// It doesn't matter how many words you have as we use words.length
for (int i = 1; i < words.length - 1; ++i) 
{
    // you could figure out a better method to add "_"
    if (i != 1)
    {
        sb.append("_");
    }
    sb.append(words[i]);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: @user3121362 - Don't forget to mark this answer as correct so your question no longer appears unanswered.